# How to check if an array inside an object contains a specific value?

Tags: typescript

I am looking the best way to check admin role with component in angular.

I have the following code in component

```
checkIfIsAdmin(): any {
  let user_string = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");

  if (!isNullOrUndefined([user_string])) {
    console.log(user_string);
    return true;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I need to check the `ROLE_ADMIN` that I receive with the following format:

```
{
    "longId": 4,
    "name": "bbb",
    "email": "bbb@gmail.com",
    "userName": "bbb",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI0IiwiaWF0IjoxNTU5NDk0NTczLCJleHAiOjE1NTk0OTQ4NzN9.XmSHywZv09b4BR9-NxyCTVPF33pLsk3QtTEXQMQF4YHW7i27Ghj2Uh3WZAegpG4rdSImKcm1wMgJsPLpHcTyew",
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_USER",
        "ROLE_ADMIN"
    ]
}
```

I don't know how to iterate roles inside `if` condition, could anyone help me ?

Comment: `return user_string.roles.indexOf("Role_Admin") > 0`

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you asking how to deserialize a JSON string? Or how to access a property of an object? Or how to loop through an array? Or how to use an array method that would test it the array contains a given value? Also, please, your method return type should be `boolean`, not any.

Comment: I think you mean ```return user_string.roles.indexOf("Role_Admin") > -1```

Comment: Guys: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: The question is well posed with example, and this is good, welcome on StackOverflow! But the title is misleading, and this question is really about how to iterate through a typescript/javascript object -- which is a well-covered topic and you will find your answer if you rather look for that.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, I am assuming that -

```
user_string = {"longId":4,"name":"bbb","email":"bbb@gmail.com","userName":"bbb","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI0IiwiaWF0IjoxNTU5NDk0NTczLCJleHAiOjE1NTk0OTQ4NzN9.XmSHywZv09b4BR9-NxyCTVPF33pLsk3QtTEXQMQF4YHW7i27Ghj2Uh3WZAegpG4rdSImKcm1wMgJsPLpHcTyew","roles":["ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"]}
```

If my understanding is correct then do the following -

```
checkIfIsAdmin(): any {
  let user_string = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
  const user = JSON.parse(user_string);
  if (user ["roles"]) {
    const roles = user["roles"];
    const index = roles.indexOf("ROLE_ADMIN");
    return index >= 0;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(user_string)` which convert this string to object.

For example:

```
const userData = JSON.parse(user_string);
return userData["roles"].indexOf("ROLE_ADMIN") !== -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
checkIfIsAdmin(): any {
  let user_string = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
  return !!user_string && user_string.roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN')
}

//user_string is undefined  result=false
//user_string contains "ROLE_ADMIN  result = true
//user_string does not contain "ROLE_ADMIN" result =false
```